# Neo4J Path Query on Subgraph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the shortest path between two nodes in a graph. The graph is quite large and has around 1 million nodes (and will grow in the future). As path finding complexity explodes with the length of the path I want to keep all my possible paths small. Therefore I wanted to only run the path query on a sub-graph of the original graph. This should reduce the graph size by about 1/3. There are 3 different node labels: TypeA, TypeB, TypeC. 
I thought that running a MATCH followed by a WITH passes only the matched data to the subsequent MATCHes. However when I run:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n:TypeA OR n:TypeB WITH n 
MATCH p = shortestPath((n:TypeA {hash: "<some-hash>"})-[r*]-(e:TypeA {hash: "<some-other-hash>"})) 
RETURN p
```

The nodes of the path should only be TypeA or TypeB. However I see that the found path can also traverse over TypeC nodes (they are included in the result).

An alternative query I thought about is the following however it seems that its performance is far inferior as it does not even finish.

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((n:TypeA {hash: "<some-hash>"})-[r*]-(e:TypeA {hash: "<some-other-hash>"})) 
WHERE ALL ( x IN nodes(p) WHERE x:TypeA OR x:TypeB ) 
RETURN path
```

What am I missing with MATCH-WITH in regards to performing queries on subgraphs?
Is there an alternative way to find a path between two nodes that only traverses certain labels?

I have found solutions to the second question however all of them include traversing the full graph and *then* check if a path satisfies the label-constraint. I need something more performant for the graphs I am dealing with.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

EDIT:
DB schema clarification. The labels that can be connected is highly restricted.

- TypeA can be connected to: TypeA, TypeB
- TypeB can be connected to: TypeA, TypeC
- TypeC can be connected to: TypeB

(:A)--(:A)--(:B)--(:C)

Where each :A has one predecessor and one successor of type :A.
One :A can have many :B connected
One :B has at most one :A connected
One :B can have many :C connected
One :C hast at most one :B connected

This structure means that you could also think of the graph in 3 layers. I  wanted to "cut" off one layer (of :A) to reduce the subgraph. Is there any way to run a subsequent (path-)query on only a sub-set of the graph? To my understanding this was the purpose of WITH. I guess I understood that incorrectly.

Comment: The behavior of your first query is right because you are restricting start and end nodes by type, but has no restriction to the nodes between start and end nodes.

Comment: Also, have you tried indexing the hash property?

Comment: If you can use APOC, there are procedure to [expand paths](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths). Also, if you're not restricted to using a Cypher-based API, you might consider using the [traversal framework](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas about expand path procedure: is there a way to get the shortest path with it? That is: get the shortest path restricting the node labels between start and end nodes...

Comment: You're correct, APOC's current expand will not work in this case.

Comment: Your tactic for dividing your DB into thirds seems to be flawed. I will assume that the 3 node labels are of roughly equal prevalence. Unless nodes with a particular label can only be connected to other nodes with the same label, the tactic of looking for paths involving only nodes with a particular label will give you less (possibly very much less) than a third of the overall results.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! I missed the Hash index on one Label. I updated that and am running a query now.

About the structure of the DB please see the edit in my original post.